# Print string "like" the interactive interpreter?

Tags: python, string

I like the way Python interactive interpreter prints strings, and I want to repeat that specifically in scripts. However, I can't seem to do that.

Example. I can do this in interpreter:

```
>>> a="d\x04"
>>> a
'd\x04'
```

However, I cannot replicate this in the python itself

```
$ python -c 'a="d\x04";print a'
d
```

I want this because I want to debug a code with a lot of string with similar non-printable characters.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: `print("{!r}".format(a))` wil also work

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Does `print "%r"%a` also mean the same?

Comment: @BhargavRao, yes it is the repr output also

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Then  why was my answer downvoted?

Comment: was it downvoted before you changed added %r?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham chuck it. Thanks to the down vote I got a hat. Yippee. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

```
>>> a = 'd\x04'
>>> a
'd\x04'
>>> print(a)
d
>>> repr(a)
"'d\\x04'"
>>> print(repr(a))
'd\x04'
```

Comment: I will accept your answer because it's better formated than my own :) thanks

Comment: You might get a hat if you accept your own question :D

Comment: Haha, well that's nice, but hats are for a few days while answers on SO stay for years :)

Answer (score 6):

Oh, that was fast.

I can just use `repr()` functon. That is, in my example,

```
python -c 'a="d\x04";print repr(a)'
```

Comment: That is exactly what the interactive interpreter uses: if the result of the expression is not `None` it prints the `repr()`

Answer (score 0):

Make it a raw string (If possible)

```
$ python -c 'a=r"d\x04";print a'
d\x04
$ python -c 'a="d\x04";print "%r"%a'
d\x04
```

EDIT

As you said that you cannot make it a raw string, Then you will have to use `repr()` as stated in the other answer..

Comment: That makes it a completely different string.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have a string that's not a "raw string" and I can't modify it in this way.